# How do I link my Profile table to my AspNetUsers table when registering?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-core, guid

So I'm making a .NET Core app with MVC and I'm wondering how I can make a new profile and at the same time put the id of that row in my AspNetUsers as "ProfileId" when someone registers.

Here's my Profile.cs :

```
namespace Overnight.Models
{
      public enum GenderType : byte {
        Unknown = 0,
        Male = 1,
        Female = 2,
        NotApplicable = 9
    }
    public class Profile : BaseEntity<Int64>
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; } 
        public GenderType Gender { get; set; }
        public Nullable<DateTime> DayOfBirth { get; set; } 
        public Nullable<DateTime> LastActivityDate { get; set; }
        //TODO One to One reference for image and adress 
        public List<ProfileReview> Reviews { get; set; }
        public List<Blog> Blogs { get; set; } 
         public List<Accomodation> Accomodations { get; set; } 
        public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
         public List<Wishlist> Wishlists { get; set; }
        public List<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
        public List<Discount> Discounts { get; set; }

        public Security.ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Here's my ApplicationUser.cs :

```
namespace Overnight.Models.Security
{
     public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid> 
     {
         public string PlainPassword  { get; set; }

         public DateTime CreatedAt {get; set;}

        public Nullable<DateTime> UpdatedAt {get; set;}

        public  Nullable<DateTime> DeletedAt {get; set;}

        public Int64 ProfileId { get; set; }

        public Profile Profile { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here's the code for registering in my AccountController.cs :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
        {

            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email};    
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {

                    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    _logger.LogInformation(3, "User created a new account with password.");
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so not sure if this is the best approach but I think you should first create a `profile` and then insert it into `AspNetUser` table, you also have to come up with a 'rollback' mechanism, either using stored procedures or manually track your work and backtrack if anything goes wrong.

so make your `RegisterViewModel` to contain information needed to create a `Profile`, and before creating `user`, there should be a line like:

```
var profile = profileRepo.add(new profile { /* use registerViewModel to fill*/});
profleRepo.SaveChanges(); // now your profile has the Id of last inserted row
```

then you can do this:

```
 var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, profileId = profile.Id};
```

Comment: thanks for the response! Your code seems to give no errors in the editor but when I hit register it gives the error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.This error is given with the first line of your code. Is it because "new Profile" returns null?

Comment: So basically when you try to add a new profile, it gives you the error?

Comment: anyhow, please debug the add profile method and check what value is missing, there should be a value that you are not providing in the profile object to the add method. simply try to insert a new profile, since it has no dependency on any other table, should be a straight forward procedure.
create a profile object with FirstName, LastName, Gender and the dates and it should get inserted with no problem.

Comment: one more thing :D, you might have to instantiate your lists in profile's constructor like this `public profile(){ this.reviews = new hashset<Review>() ... }`

Comment: I found the problem but I'm not sure how to solve it. It's not the profile that returns null but it's my database (DbContext). So my database just won't open. It's strange because DbContext does work in my backoffice but not in my AccountController which isn't in my "backoffice area"... :/

Comment: I think you have forgotten to inject your mainContext in this controller, I am not sure if you have one or two contexts, but if you have used the default Identity, your Account controller has an IdentityContext, which contains the Identity tables (aspnetuser, ...) and the rest of your classes like profile are in another context like mainContext (this can totally be wrong and you have only one context :D)

Comment: I have only one context :/ I injected it with this code: public ApplicationDbContext ApplicationDbContext { get; set; } It works in all my controllers in the backoffice but not in in my accountController :(. I'm really trying to figure out what I did wrong...

Comment: so im not a expert on this, but the code you mentioned does not inject anything :D, but if you have one context, account controller does automatically injects identityContext. let me put it this way, when you create a new project with idenity, a context with the name IdentityContext get created, this is the context that accountController uses to login, register ..., also people usually create another context (ApplicationDbContext in your case) to create their own tables. again I am not sure what you have done but just to be sure check if your applicationdbcontext inherits from `DbContext` or

Comment: wait a minute :D  I think I mislead you with my last comments, you have to make sure your context is injected in profile repository not account controller

Comment: Ok thanks :) so my profile repository is that my model (Profile.cs)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly, but generally put, you have a repository in which you do CRUD operations in (like profle.Add), but you might not have one, anyhow, please go to your backbone controller (or where ever it was you said it was working), create a mock profile and try to insert it, if it worked, check what has been injected into this controller and make sure the same are inserted in account controller too, or you can copy it and edit your question so I can see it